# Studying a function

Tags: limits, functions

Consider the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} (9^x + 4^x - 6^x)^{\frac{1}{x}} & \text{ for } x \in \mathbb {R}\setminus\{0\} \\ a & \text{ for } x = 0 \end{cases}$$

where $a \in \mathbb R$ so that the function $f$ is continuous.

I have found $a = 6$ and $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 9$$

and I have to find:

**1)The number of solution of the equation $f(x) \cdot f(-x) = 36$**

For this I have observed that $x = 0$ is a solution.

**2) $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$$**

I have written the function as $$e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln(9^x + 4^x - 6^x)}$$ but I wasn't just as easy as the limit to $+\infty$.

**3) $f'(0) = \: ?$**

Comment: $$(9^x+4^x-6^x)^{1/x}=9\left[\left(1+\dfrac{4^x-6^x}{9^x}\right)^{9^x/(4^x-6^x)}\right]^{(4^x-6^x)/x9^x}$$

Now $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(4/9)^x-(6/9)^x}x=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(4/9)^x-1}x-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(6/9)^x-1}x=\ln(4/9)-\ln(6/9)=\ln(4/6)=\ln(2/3)$

$$\lim_{x\to0}(9^x+4^x-6^x)^{1/x}=9e^{\ln2/3}=9\cdot\dfrac23=?$$

Comment: $f(x)f(-x)=(\frac{9^x+4^x-6^x}{9^{-x}+4^{-x}-6^{-x}})^{\frac{1}{x}}=36$ This gives $\frac{9^x+4^x-6^x}{(1/9)^{x}+(1/4)^{x}-(1/6)^{x}}=36^x$ and so $9^x+4^x-6^x=36^x((1/9)^{x}+(1/4)^{x}-(1/6)^{x})=4^x+9^x-6^x$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't know what you've missed but the answer should be $6 \cdot (\ln \frac{3}{2})^2$

Comment: @Liviu That is $f'(0)$, but the post is about the limit for x tending to $0$, which you already have found.

Comment: @Peter Well, I said I had found $a = 6$ in the beginning (so I have found that limit)

Comment: @Liviu Yes, I only wanted to point out what $6\cdot (\ln\frac{3}{2})^2$ is.

Comment: @Peter Could you give me a hint on finding $f'(0)$ ?

Comment: @Liviu More difficult than I thought ...